# Turing machine adding two numbers

Tags: turing-machines

How can I create Turing Machine which will calculate sum of two binary digits separated by #, eg. 111#101B, where B is for blank? Result can be written at the end of the tape.

Comment: Is this homework?  (Just asking)

Comment: We arent going to give you answers to your homework. You need to at least show that you have tried and ask specific questions where you are having trouble.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I just wanted to have a clue like in answer below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Write a turing machine to convert both binary numbers to unary (maintaining the blank between them).
2. Write a turing machine to replace the blank with a 1, and chop a digit off the end.
3. Write a turing machine to convert a unary number to binary.
4. Chain those three machines together.

Comment: I hate playing the necromancer, but this comes up when you google for "add binary numbers turing machine linear time". And _no_ this one is in no way an efficient solution since it takes an exponential number of steps (in original input size).

Answer (score 2):

assuming input a#(1)b
convert to a#(1)b#(2)c#(3)BLANK

Blank will be filled with sum. Make 2 cases for LSB of 'a'. Further divide 2 cases for LSB of 'b'. 'c' is the carry bit that is initially 0. Make seperate 2 cases for each of the four cases and update the carry bit on the way. Path is chosen based on if 'c' was 0 or 1.

Picture shows a rough sketch.

[image]

Final result will be reversed value of original sum. You reverse this again. Take the pic with a grain of salt. It is just a rough sketch. Nomenclature is not followed.